# Magento 2 : showing price difference not working when configurable options clicked

Tags: price, magento2.2, special-price, configurable-price

I have override `app/design/vendor_name/themename/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml` file but It doesn't change while click on configurable options.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
?>
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('List Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Sale Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <?php 
        $old = $priceModel->getValue();  
        $special = $block->getSaleableItem()->getMinimalPrice();
        if(!$special)
            $special = $block->getSaleableItem()->getFinalPrice();
    ?>
    <div class="saveCost">        
        <?php 
            $priceHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
            $percent = (($old-$special)*100/$old);
            $finalSave = $old-$special;
            $formattedPrice = $priceHelper->currency($finalSave, true, false);
            echo __('You Save: '). $formattedPrice . "&nbsp;&nbsp;" . "(" . round($percent).'%)';
        ?>
    </div>
    
    <div style="display:none;" class="product-qualify"><p>This Product Qualifies for<br><b>Free Shipping</b></p></div> 
    
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl() ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Output of this code: (Without click of any configurable option)
[image]

But after click on any configurable option Price changed but saved price didn't change.
[image]

I want to change you save value. Can anyone help?